# how to resize image after load image from server

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I want to resize image when image will be load from server url. I am using Picasso Library for load and show image. But image size is too large so my app going to slow. I want to solve this. I want to resize image but don't work. I was use this code:

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(dataReturn.getImage()).resize(720,720).centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.upload_image)
                .into(holder.img);
```

But I am fail to show image. When i use this code, there image not showing in Image view. load Error. What i can do now

Comment: What errors are showing in the log? Please also check image URL is valid or not.

Comment: if image is OK, try to downgrade the image dimensions. instead of 720*720 try 300*300

Comment: @Tausif there is no error show